# My Laragon Can't Show my web project, but download it

Tags: laragon

i use laragon. I'm having problems when calling a website on localhost. the website doesn't display but the index file is downloaded instead, has anyone experienced the same thing. Please help me

someone share their experience how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I had a similar case with Laragon, and the issue was caused by an incorrect .htaccess configuration. In addition to modifying the .htaccess, I also recreated a new website with Laragon and moved all my files from one website to another, and that resolved the problem.